# Google Voice vs SMS for two-factor authentication

Tags: multi-factor, sms

I'm trying to set up two-factor authentication for all my accounts. Some of them, unfortunately, only support SMS.

In that case, which of these options would be more secure?

1. SMS
2. Google Voice (which has a strong and unique password, guarded with a physical security key).

Are there any other ways I can make these accounts more secure?

Comment: Please do not add "thank yous" or sign-offs, or salutations. They are mostly seen as noise.

Comment: probably google voice, since you can reach it over the web. SMS has a few more outsider interception potentials. Then again, if someone's owned your PC, which is common, then SMS would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any form of 2-Factor Authentication adds account security. Verification codes sent by texts or calls can be vulnerable to phone number-based hacks. Attackers can get your Google Voice password as well as your normal account password. They could then get past the two-factor authentication.

If you always access Google Voice from a separate system you'd still technically be two-factor though.

Comment: "Attackers can get your Google Voice password as well as your normal account password." -- how? I'm not sure you have answered which is better.

Comment: You can put your whole Google account behind 2FA, including access to SMS or MMS messages in Voice. Assuming this was a more secure 2FA than an SMS by self (which is subject to things like SIM hijacking), what's the problem?